# How do I get to move focus to another input element when the previous one has reached a particular size?

Tags: javascript

I want all my inputs to get focus depending on whether the previous element has reached a particular size. The code works and it does the right thing but when I use my mouse to select an input which has the maximum inputs already and try to input elements again, it allows the input elements and that's not what I want. I want it to be smart enough to know that the field has enough values and cannot take in another. I'm aware of the `maxlength` but I'm not allowed to use that.

```
const smartCursor = (event, fieldIndex, fields) => {
    if (fields[fieldIndex].value.length === fields[fieldIndex].size) {
        if (fields[fieldIndex + 1]) {
            fields[fieldIndex + 1].focus();
        }else {
            fields[fieldIndex].blur();
        }
    }
};

const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('input');
inputFields.forEach((field, index, fields) => {
    field.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
        smartCursor(event, index, fields);
    }, false);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `keyup` listener you're running the `smartCursor` function after they character has already been entered into the input element. Therefore, clicking your mouse back into that input and hitting a character will add the character before running `smartCursor`.

You'll probably want a second listener for `keydown`.

```
const smartCursor = (event, fieldIndex, fields) => {
    const isBackspaceOrDelete = event.which === 8 || event.which === 46;
    if (!isBackspaceOrDelete && fields[fieldIndex].value.length === fields[fieldIndex].size) {
        if (fields[fieldIndex + 1]) {
            fields[fieldIndex + 1].focus();
        }else {
            fields[fieldIndex].blur();
        }
    }
};

const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('input');
inputFields.forEach((field, index, fields) => {
    field.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
        smartCursor(event, index, fields);
    }, false);
    field.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
        smartCursor(event, index, fields);
    }, false);
})
```

Comment: It works but I tried deleting an input that is up to the size and it just switches focus to the next element. It switches focus to the next field which and then deletes from that field

Comment: Good point. You can check the `which` property on the event to make sure it isn't the Delete or Backspace key. I've modified the example above to reflect that.